# Why execve and brk(NULL) are always the first two system calls?

Tags: system-calls

When I try

```
strace ping google.com
```

or

```
strace ls
```

or

```
even strace curl <domain>
```

The first two systemcalls are always,

```
execve("/usr/bin/curl", ["curl", "google.com"], 0x7ffecf1bc378 /* 61 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55f553c49000
```

Can someone please tell me if execve will always be the first systemcall when I execute anything?

I read this manual page, https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve
But don't understand if `execve` is really a system call or executable program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Linux a new process is created via [`fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), which makes a child process which is almost identical to the parent process.  To create a new process whose program is *different* than the program of the original process, the new child process immediately calls `execve()`, which is basically the process saying "replace my current program with this other program".

[`brk(NULL)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/brk) is the process asking where its [heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308762/1020588) ends.  Many programs call this as their first system call (which will show up right after `execve()`) because they use `malloc()` right away (or a library call they make uses `malloc()` internally).  If the program and its library calls don't need to call `malloc()` for a while then something besides `brk(NULL)` will be the second system call.

Comment: Linux's `brk(0)` actually just checks the current break, it doesn't change it yet.

Comment: Oops, I'd glossed over that brk()'s argument was NULL/0. (And I didn't know about it special behavior on that value)

Comment: but that doesn't explain why `brk(NULL)` is the 2nd system call. Well I just realized it is not always the 2nd systemcall. When I run `strace ping google.com`, I get `access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` as a 2nd call after `execve`

Comment: @MaverickD added more details to my answer.

Comment: I know this is late but is the reason that `strace` does not register the invocation of the `fork()` call, that it is made by the parent process and `strace` only tracks what the child does ? Also in this case, the parent process would simply be the shell right ?

Answer (score 1):

I think all those syscalls are just the dynamic linker setting up stuff before execution. I made a little test program to check this out.

```
me@bar:~/foo$ cat main.c
#include <unistd.h>
void main(){
        syscall(60,0);
}
```

now we compile it first statically and then dynamically.
the `-Wl,-emain` argument tells gcc to pass `-emain` to the linker, that means set `main` as the entry point. And sure enough the program exits immediately.

```
me@bar:~/foo$ gcc -static main.c -Wl,-emain -o main
me@bar:~/foo$ strace ./main 2>&1 | head
execve("./main", ["./main"], 0x7fff6d7c4b40 /* 50 vars */) = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

now without the `-static` flag, we get what you usually see.

```
me@bar:~/foo$ gcc main.c -Wl,-emain -o main
me@bar:~/foo$ strace ./main 2>&1 | head
execve("./main", ["./main"], 0x7fff06b48d20 /* 50 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558c61a90000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd68e8e950) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=77239, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 77239, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe55ed7e000
...
```

Even though the code is meant to jump directly to `main`!

now I thought that might be specific to libc, maybe it needs to set itself up or something like that. but actually its not, I tried making a little dynamic library to link with, and then on the strace the following showed up:

```
$ ldd main
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff9c8cd000)
    libfoo.so => /home/me/path/to/libfoo.so (0x00007f80ed20a000)


$ strace ./main
execve("./main", ["./main"], 0x7ffcdf5b5a70 /* 51 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/me/path/to/libfoo.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=13240, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f028541c000
mmap(NULL, 16384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0285418000
mmap(0x7f0285419000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f0285419000
mmap(0x7f028541a000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f028541a000
mmap(0x7f028541b000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f028541b000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f028541d040) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f028541d310)         = 6310
set_robust_list(0x7f028541d320, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7f028541d960, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7f028541b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x402000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I'm not sure what most of the calls there are doing, but its pretty clear they are just mapping my little `libfoo` (actually a single function that just executes the exit syscall) in memory. So these traces are clearly from the dynamic linker, mapping the dynamic library into memory (after opening it on filedescriptor 3) and then  handing over execution to the program proper (which in this case is merely exiting immediately).
Now, i guess the `brk` call is there because the dynamic linker needs to work out the memory layout the program will have during runtime, so it needs to do some math with that value. Linux being free software, this is probably explained somewhere in the source for the dynamic linker.
Hope this helps.