# Is the first mmap call after execv() mapping of the new process?

Tags: linux, process

Suppose I have the following bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

ls *.py
```

Now I run `strace -f ./test.sh`, I see the following in the output:

```
[pid 25916] execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls", "test2.py", "test.py"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
[pid 25916] brk(NULL)                   = 0x1c7a000
[pid 25916] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbb616ae000
[pid 25916] access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 25916] open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

I undertand the `brk()` part from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464974/why-execve-and-brknull-are-always-the-first-two-system-calls), but what about the `mmap()` call?

Is that mapping of the process image (partial)? Or by the time `brk()` is called, the new child process's image has already been replaced?

Comment: That's all stuff done by the dynamic linker (`/lib*/ld-linux*`), without any deep meaning -- the mmap is just allocating a chunk of anonymous memory, probably to read the content of `/etc/ld.so.cache` into it in order to parse it.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the `mmap` pre the `cache` file?